# How to get Referral URL Links from Sitecore Analytics or DMS

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-dms, sitecore-analytics

I would like to know is there any way to get the url links of referring sites.

For example: If someone shared an article link to my site on Facebook, using sitecore analytic is there a way for me to store or retrieve the link that was shared on Facebook, which brought the user to my site in the first place.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Christina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each visit in DMS stores the URL of its referrer (if any) as a field in the database.

For instance, here's an SQL query that returns a list of referrers for all first visits (i.e. the visits that brought each visitor to your site for the first time).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  Referrer
FROM
  Visits
WHERE
  VisitorVisitIndex = 1
  AND Referrer <> ''
```

Comment: Hi @DmytroShevchenko, ok.. i've managed to get the facebooks links however, I noticed the urls have extra parameters appended to them.. any idea why? for example : **http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=<my site link>&h=<some id>&enc=<some id>&s=1**  Notice the extra params u / h / enc / s=1

Comment: @RiverPaul I believe this is Facebook's URL wrapping handler. When you post a link on Facebook, it sometimes wraps it into `l.php?u=...` URLs to track clicks.